# Parse huge XML file with VTD-XML

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

To execute a XPATH query in huge xml file I read many articles that prefere VTD-XML to does it so I copied this code which was in those articles :

```
import com.ximpleware.extended.*;
public class MainVTD {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception{
        VTDGenHuge vg = new VTDGenHuge();
        if (vg.parseFile("./resource/init/dblp_3.xml",true,VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED)){
            VTDNavHuge vnh = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilotHuge aph = new AutoPilotHuge(vnh);
            aph.selectXPath("/*/*[not(name() = name(preceding-sibling::*[1]))]");
            int i ;
            while ((i=aph.evalXPath())!=-1){
                System.out.println(" element name is "+vnh.toString(i));
            }
        }else System.out.println("Doc not mapped");
    }
}
```

but when I run it without result , so that's mean XML file it was not mapped in memory ... **my question is how I can force mapping xml file in VTD-XML ?**

Comment: how big is your xml file?

Comment: I just tested for 1.5G file , althought that I'did not have any result

Comment: it could be that xml isn't well formed, or you got a wrong file name, among many other reasons, so catch the exception and print it out to see what exactly is causing the problem...

Comment: it does not throw any exception it just exit because vg.parseFile("./resource/init/dblp_3.xml",true,VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED) = false , so vtd-xml don't map all the fille in memory , thats what i sepose !!

Comment: turn memory mapping into false, and see what happens...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author no way i tried to without memory mapping .. it's a same result no thing !

Comment: I will send you a code snippet for you to test in a short while

Comment: Nice @vtd-xml-author because I don't find any solution for a moment

Comment: Just use jQuery. .....Kidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the follow code piece in and print out the exception to see what is wrong...

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ximpleware.extended.*;
public class testExtendedVTD {
    public static void main(String s[]){
        VTDGenHuge vgh = new VTDGenHuge();
        XMLBuffer xb = new XMLBuffer(); //or XMLMemeMappedBuffer
        try {
            xb.readFile("test.xml");
            vgh.setDoc(xb);
        } catch (ParseExceptionHuge e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but without success , it catched an exception :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: your answer doesn't seem to make any sense to me... that is not a vtd related exception ...

Comment: I corrected this error , it was a problem in file , it was not wellformed ... Thank you @vtd-xml-author